# Rails remove subarray from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In my Rails 5 app I have something like this:

```
a = [1,2,3]

a.map do |entry|
  entry.delete if condition == true
end
```

This removes the entry if the condition is true.

Now I have this:

```
a = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]

a.map do |entry|
  entry.delete if condition == true
end
```

This loops through a but now `entry` is an array and delete should remove the entire `entry` but instead I get:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
```

Dos anybody know how I can loop through an array of arrays and remove an entire subarray?

Answer (score 5):

Try this: 
`a.delete_if {condition}`

For example:

```
a = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
a.delete_if {|entry| entry[0] == 1 } 
# returns [[2, 3], [3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using map you should use flat_map see: https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/flat_map